# How can I draw the shapes with gradient colors as shown in the below figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, tcolorbox, tikz-styles, shapes

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside, a4paper, titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames, svgnames, xllsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[left=0.1cm, right=0.1cm, top=0.1cm, bottom=0.1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, shapes, positioning, shadows}

\definecolor{RollBack}{RGB}{224, 207, 196}
\title{sdfld}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\tcbset{colframe=gray!0, colback=RollBack, arc=0mm}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\begin{minipage}{4.5cm}
\hspace*{0.4cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\fill[fill=Brown!20]([xshift=1.48mm, yshift=-1.5mm]current page.north west) --++(0.05\paperwidth, 0) --++(0.12\paperwidth, -2.3) --++(-0.12\paperwidth, -2.3) --++(-0.05\paperwidth, -0) --cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace*{4cm}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{18cm}
\begin{center}
\Huge{\textcolor{white}{ABC}}\\
\vspace*{0.5cm}
\Large{\textcolor{white}{\emph{Designer | Graphics}}}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your code fails to compile. Please fix it.

Comment: Off-topic: `\Huge` and `\Large` etc. don't take arguments. They are just switches. `\Huge{word}` will make all following text huge until the end of the current group or a different size command is used.

Comment: This is not a free design - I doubt you own the rights, so I would a advise to make something similar instead.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `\shade` to get the basic effect.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[blue!10] (0,0) rectangle (12,4);
\shade[left color=blue!30, right color=blue!50] (0,0)--(1,0)--(3,2)--(1,4)--(0,4)--cycle;
\shade[left color=blue!10, right color=blue!20] (1,0)--(4,3)--(5,2)--(3,0)--cycle;
\shade[left color=blue!10, right color=blue!30] (1,4)--(3,2)--(4,3)--(3,4)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not very efficient, but something like this? I haven't actually shaded them, but you have [Sandy G's code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/712590/) for that.

[image: layered shading]

The basic idea is to layer shapes which are partially transparent, so the colours build up from lighter to darker. I also simplified the code a little bit by removing the `minipage`s and including the text into the picture.

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside, a4paper, titlepage]{article}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/712617/ addaswyd o gwestiwn Vishakha: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/712585/
\usepackage[dvipsnames, svgnames, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[left=0.1cm, right=0.1cm, top=0.1cm, bottom=0.1cm]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,positioning}

\definecolor{RollBack}{RGB}{224, 207, 196}
\title{sdfld}
\date{}

\newlength\lengtha
\newlength\lengthb
\newlength\lengthc
\begin{document}
\tcbset{colframe=gray!0, colback=RollBack, arc=0mm}

\begin{tcolorbox}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \setlength \lengtha{0.12\paperwidth}
    \setlength \lengthb{23mm}
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
      \fill[fill=Brown,opacity=.1]([xshift=1.48mm, yshift=-1.5mm]current page.north west) coordinate (a1) --++(0.22\paperwidth,0) coordinate (b1) --++(\lengtha,-\lengthb) coordinate (c1) -- ([yshift=-\lengthb]c1-|b1) coordinate (d1) -- (a1|-d1) coordinate (e1) --cycle;
    \end{scope}
    \fill[fill=Brown,opacity=.1](a1) coordinate (a2) --++(0.05\paperwidth, 0) coordinate (b2) --++(\lengtha, -2.3) coordinate (c2) -- (b2|-d1) coordinate (d2) -- (d2-|a2) coordinate (e2) --cycle;
    \pgfmathsetmacro \tempres {atan(\lengthb/\lengtha)}
    \pgfmathsetlength \lengthc {2\lengthb/sin(\tempres)}
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
      \clip (a1) -- (b1) -- (c1) -- (d1) -- (e1) -- cycle;
      \fill[fill=Brown,opacity=.1](a1)   -- (e2)  -- (d2) -- ++(\tempres:\lengthc) coordinate (f) --  (a2) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
    \node (abc) [text=white,font=\Huge,anchor=south]at ([xshift=37.5mm,yshift=2mm]current page.center |- c1) {ABC};
    \node [below=2mm of abc |- c1,anchor=north,font=\Large\itshape,text=white] {Designer \textbar{} Graphics};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \vspace*{4cm}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

### Edit

This version shades the shapes but, unlike Sandy G's answer, a `radial` shading is used and clipped. This gives a somewhat more subtle effect than my original result.

[image: layered with shadings]

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside, a4paper, titlepage]{article}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/712617/ addaswyd o gwestiwn Vishakha: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/712585/
\usepackage[dvipsnames, svgnames, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[left=0.1cm, right=0.1cm, top=0.1cm, bottom=0.1cm]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,positioning,shadings}

\definecolor{RollBack}{RGB}{224, 207, 196}
\title{sdfld}
\date{}

\newlength\lengtha
\newlength\lengthb
\newlength\lengthc
\begin{document}
\tcbset{colframe=gray!0, colback=RollBack, arc=0mm}

\begin{tcolorbox}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \setlength \lengtha{0.12\paperwidth}
    \setlength \lengthb{23mm}
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
      \clip ([xshift=1.48mm, yshift=-1.5mm]current page.north west) coordinate (a1) --++(0.22\paperwidth,0) coordinate (b1) --++(\lengtha,-\lengthb) coordinate (c1) -- ([yshift=-\lengthb]c1-|b1) coordinate (d1) -- (a1|-d1) coordinate (e1) --cycle;
      \path [inner color=white,outer color=Brown,opacity=.1] (a1 |- c1) circle (.22\paperwidth+\lengtha);
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
      \clip(a1) coordinate (a2) --++(0.05\paperwidth, 0) coordinate (b2) --++(\lengtha, -2.3) coordinate (c2) -- (b2|-d1) coordinate (d2) -- (d2-|a2) coordinate (e2) --cycle;
      \path [inner color=white,outer color=Brown,opacity=.1](a1 |- c1) circle (.05\paperwidth+\lengtha);
    \end{scope}
    \pgfmathsetmacro \tempres {atan(\lengthb/\lengtha)}
    \pgfmathsetlength \lengthc {2\lengthb/sin(\tempres)}
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
      \clip(a1)   -- (e2)  -- (d2) -- ++(\tempres:\lengthc) coordinate (f) --  (a2) -- cycle;
      \path [inner color=white,outer color=Brown,opacity=.1] (a1 |- c1) circle (.22\paperwidth+\lengtha);
    \end{scope}
    \node (abc) [text=white,font=\Huge,anchor=south]at ([xshift=37.5mm,yshift=2mm]current page.center |- c1) {ABC};
    \node [below=2mm of abc |- c1,anchor=north,font=\Large\itshape,text=white] {Designer \textbar{} Graphics};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \vspace*{4cm}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

I wanted to integrate this into the `tcolorbox`, but I can't get it to work right now.

Comment: Thanks for both the answers. But how can I get to know about the positioning of coordinates of shapes?.

Comment: @Vishakha I just used the ones you provided in your code and tweaked the additions until the result approximated the image you posted. So I'm not sure what you are asking exactly? Or do you mean the names? I just gave each new coordinate a name: a1, b1 etc.

Comment: Actually I'm new to latex so got bit confused about the coordinates used for the different shapes thus wanted to know more of that?

Comment: @Vishakha Where I write `... coordinate (name) ...`, I'm naming a coordinate. Once I've done that, I can use `(name)` for that coordinate. It saves a bit of typing but, more importantly, it makes it easier to tweak dimensions if necessary later. You could name them more meaningfully e.g. `top left` rather than `a1` or whatever. Once I've done that, I can also use `(name 1 |- name 2)` to refer to the point vertically aligned with `(name 1)` and horizontally aligned with `(name 2)`. `(name 2 -| name 1)` is equivalent to `(name 1 |- name 2)`. The pgf manual explains this in more detail ;).

Comment: Thanks a lot I will deffinitely go through the documentation!